# NSURLConnection still calls delegate AFTER cancel method has been called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Having a problem with NSURLConnection, if I create a NSURLConnection and call [connection connectionWithRequest] let it load a little then call [connection cancel] most of the time that works fine.  However occasionally even after I call [connection cancel] the connection's delegate still gets called (which crashes the app).  Googling around it looks like the problem here is a race condition in the runloop, I cancel the connection and release the delegate but before the runloop cycles it calls the delegate functions -> crash.

Is there a way for me to, after I call [connection cancel] confirm the connection has actually canceled?  Even a crappy while() loop will do :(

Comment: Same issue here. Note that on the vast majority of cases, `cancel` does work properly, and neither `connectionDidFinishLoading` nor `connectionDidFailWithError` is called on the delegate. Looks like nothing short of just-in-case extension on the lifetime of the delegate object can solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not release the connection & associated storage until your delegate receives either a `connectionDidFinishLoading:` or a `connectionDidFailWithError:` message.

[Delegates are not normally retained by the object they're acting as delegate for](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18).  However in this case it is, so the delegate should not become invalid while the NSURLConnection is still referring to it, unless you're over-releasing it somehow.

Comment: @David Gelhar - In this case it is retained, but delegates are **NOT** normally retained.  From Apple's docs "Delegating objects do not (and should not) retain their delegates. However, clients of delegating objects (applications, usually) are responsible for ensuring that their delegates are around to receive delegation messages. To do this, they may have to retain the delegate in memory-managed code." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18

Comment: Except the Apple docs say that the delegate will no longer be called after cancel, so in the normal case you will never get the connectionDidFinishLoading or connectionDidFailWithError.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet run into this problem, but this could also work without tying up your delegate object:

Since all delegate methods receive the calling Connection object as a parameter and you also know your actual active Connection object (or nil), simply ignore the delegation actions by comparing the two objects. This way a cancelled "ghost" Connection object can still call the delegate but not interfere with its internals.

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveData:(NSData*) data
{
    if(connection != _URLConnection){return;}
    ...
    [_incomingData appendData:data];
    ...
}
```

where `_URLConnection` is a property in your delegate set to an active Connection, or nil.