# How to abort async http connection in iphone?

Tags: iphone, http, nsurlconnection

I initiated an async http call to the server in a viewcontroller, but it take long time sometimes.

Can I put a button on it and then abort the running http call when user clicked that button ?  and if that could be done, I'd like also implement this function when user exit current view like, navigate back to its parent view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using an NSURLConnection, just save the connection object in an ivar or property and then call [cancel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-canBeConvertedToEncoding_) when you want to cancel the connection.

Your button's action should look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)tapCancelButton:(id)sender {
    [self.connection cancel];
    self.connection = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can abort an NSURLConnection. This question / answer discusses how to do it correctly:

[NSURLConnection still calls delegate AFTER cancel method has been called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503652/nsurlconnection-still-calls-delegate-after-cancel-method-has-been-called)