# Properly cancel NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, request, nsurlconnection

I am creating my NSURLConnection like so:

```
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:serviceRequest delegate:self];
```

I have looked in the NSURLConnection documentation and apparently the cancel API works for async requests, so will that work in the scenario?

Anyway, in my other class while the NSURLConnection is in progress I try to do this:

```
[mgr.theConnection cancel];
[mgr.theConnection release];
```

However, the delegate still gets called which I do not want. So how do I properly make sure I cancel the connection so that its delegate calls are canceled as well?

Console:

```
2012-08-17 23:01:11.820 app[14097:707] Will cancel connection=(null)
2012-08-17 23:01:11.821 app[14097:707] Did cancel connection
2012-08-17 23:01:11.821 app[14097:707] Did release connection
2012-08-17 23:01:20.330 app[14097:707] didReceiveResponse
2012-08-17 23:01:20.331 app[14097:707] didReceiveData
2012-08-17 23:01:20.332 app[14097:707] connectionDidFinishLoading
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the delegate is released and receives no messages after `cancel` has been called, and that is also my experience.

Comment: Looks like you may be setting it up incorrectly - as @MartinR my experience also follows what the documentation says.

Comment: How should I set it up properly instead?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple connections sharing the same delegate?

Comment: Nope I only have one connection and that's the one I posted the code for.

Comment: Are you calling cancel from inside a delegate method?

Comment: Nope, an IBAction for a button in another class.

Comment: What delegate is getting called after cancel? What is the backtrace for that call?

Comment: The docs are wrong: evidence to the contrary [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503652/nsurlconnection-still-calls-delegate-after-cancel-method-has-been-called). I experience the same issue in the form of production crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously something is happening that is not clear. What I would suggest is adding some log messages to verify that in fact the timing is as you think:

```
// Add a simple log like (NSLog(@"%@", @"conn_del"); to all your delegate methods)

Then addend you cancelation code with this:
NSLog(@"Will cancel connection=%@", mgr.theConnection);
[mgr.theConnection cancel];
NSLog(@"Did cancel connection");
// [mgr.theConnection release]; assuming a retained property, this is not the way to do it
mgr.theConnection = nil; // this is the proper way - release and nil out the property
NSLog(@"Did release connection");
```

I've had cancel in my code and its been tested for several years, no problems. I suspect you may learn something from the test above. I would be shocked to hear you get any messages after you see "Did cancel connection" on the console, but you might between the "Will" log and it.

EDIT: per your test, either mgr or mgr's theConnection property, is nil. This is the root cause of your problem. When you figure out why its nil and fix it, the connection will cancel and the same NSLogs will show no more delegate messages afterwards.

Comment: Thanks I will try this, also take a look at my last comment above, it provides some more info about the NSURLConnection.

Comment: I saw it. I suspect mgr.theConnection is nil, or that the 'cancel' message comes later than you think it is, thus the logs.

Comment: Well you better be ready to be shocked. Look at my console edit above. I used your exact code and I NSLogged everything you told me to. This is just super weird. What else could this be?

Comment: Also I NSLogged %@ in each NSLog in the cancel method for theConnection and it is NULL each time.

Comment: This is exactly as I stated - you never cancelled it. The first log - the will cancel with NULL as mgr.theConnection clearly shows your reference is missing so nothing was ever cancelled.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used a singleton and everything works great now! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `cancel` method does **not guarantee** that more delegate messages will not be delivered.
See the following which comes from the NSURLConnection class description:

        `The -cancel message hints to the loader that a resource load
        should be abandoned but does not guarantee that more delegate
        messages will not be delivered.  If -cancel does cause the
        load to be abandoned, the delegate will be released without
        further messages.  In general, a caller should be prepared for
        -cancel to have no effect, and internally ignore any delegate
        callbacks until the delegate is released.`